# How to extract inline comments given while code review using the bitbucket-api

Tags: git, bitbucket-api

I am using http://restbrowser.bitbucket.org/

In version2 and version1 even I could find rest calls to get details of the comments given during "commit" or during "pull-request".

Bitbucket has a decent feature of inline comments for code review as in
http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/10/30/building-inline-comments-for-pull-requests-and-commits/

Unfortunately, stackoverflow dont allow me to post images directly here(due to my low reputation) Please refer to the above link for image detail of inline comments.

I tried all the api calls in restbrowser, I am not sure If i have missed some calls, but could not extract these inline comments with any of the rest call available.

```
curl --request GET --user USERNAME:PASSWORD https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/IIITSERC/ssad34/commits/ce0fda6
```

The nearest,this returns the comments during commit messages, issues and all other stuff, but not the inline comments.
Please suggest a way to extract those comments. This is needed for my research. Any help  appreciated .  Thanks in advance.

Comment: this gets me all the 1st inline comments of any pull request, any suggestion for the child comment/ replies within those inline comment?

Comment: no idea as of now. its been quite a while since i had last worked with bitbucket api.

Answer (score 3):

I have given an additional 's' /commits/ part in the url. The correct url is:

```
curl --request GET --user USERNAME:PASSWORD https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/{owner}/{repo_slug}/commit/{commid_id}/comments/
```

Thanks.